# Want to format the number in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I want to format the input which is in the form of number in EditText.The format is **01-133134-124**. I wanted first **-** after 2 number then next dash after 6 numbers.I tried but whenever I pressed delete/backspace because of the wrong entry the format stopped working and no dash is placed after input of 2 number or 6 numbers.Here is the code.Where **Enrollement** is the EditText field.

**Format :**  2digitnumber-6dignumber-3dignumber

```
Enrollement.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        Enrollement.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                    keyDel = 1;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (keyDel == 0) {
            int len = Enrollement.getText().length();
            if (len == 2) {
                int leng = Enrollement.getText().length();
                if(leng==2) {
                    Enrollement.setText(Enrollement.getText() + "-");
                    Enrollement.setSelection(Enrollement.getText().length());
                }
                } else if (len == 9) {
                int leng = Enrollement.getText().length();
                if(leng==9) {
                    Enrollement.setText(Enrollement.getText() + "-");
                    Enrollement.setSelection(Enrollement.getText().length());
                }
            }
        } else {
            keyDel = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

    }
});
```

Comment: As a workaround you can use 3 EditText with specific length in a linear layout. The way some forms ask credit card number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much easier if you changed your approach a bit. You could be always analyzing unformatted verion of your string after every single change in your `EditText`.

Try this (remember to set `android:maxLength="13"` for your `EditText`):

```
Enrollement.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    final int[] blockLengths = new int[]{2, 6, 3};
    String mUnformatted = "";

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count){
        String unformattedSeq = s.toString().replace("-", "");
        if (mUnformatted.length() == unformattedSeq.length()) {
            return; //length of text has not changed
        }

        mUnformatted = unformattedSeq;
        //formatting sequence
        StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder();
        int blockIndex = 0;
        int currentBlock = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mUnformatted.length(); ++i) {
            if (currentBlock == blockLengths[blockIndex]) {
                formatted.append("-");
                currentBlock = 0;
                blockIndex++;
            }
            formatted.append(mUnformatted.charAt(i));
            currentBlock++;
        }

        Enrollement.setText(formatted.toString());
        Enrollement.setSelection(formatted.length());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after){
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){
    }
});
```

This code should work correctly. You could only improve the `setSelection` part (currently if you delete a number in the middle of your `EditText` it will move your cursor to the end of the text).

Answer (score 0):

In your `onTextChanged` method you could do:

```
String str = YourEditText.getText().toString();

if((str.length()==2 && len <str.length()) || (str.length()==6 && len <str.length())){

 YourEditText.append("-"); }
```

Also,

```
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = YourEditText.getText().toString();
    len = str.length();
   }
```

Adapted from [this](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-apply-niccustom-format-to-edit.html) article.